# How can I combine two tables together using the JQuery Datatable serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, datatables

I am using a great example of a serverside coldfusion jquery datatable I found at the following website. [Site Here](http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/4/29/JQuery-Datatables-plugin-example-using-a-server-side-data-request-coldfusion)

The issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to add a second table in the lookup. For example, in the primary table, location_id is listed, yet I need the location_name listed in another table.

As you can see in the example you list the table to use.

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        aoData.push(
            { "name": "table", "value": "ukLocationCodes" },
            { "name": "sql", "value": "SELECT [id], [varCode], [varLocation]" }
            );
```

Then on the ColdFusion database page it uses the results query to get the search request.

```
<cfquery name="rResult" datasource="A8002CMS">
    #preservesinglequotes(form.sql)#
    FROM #form.table#

    WHERE 1 = 1
<cfif len(form.sSearch)>
        AND (
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(variables.fieldlist)#" index="variables.index">
#listGetAt(variables.fieldlist, variables.index,',')# LIKE '%#form.sSearch#%' <cfif variables.index LT listLen(variables.fieldlist)> OR </cfif>
</cfloop>
    )
</cfif>

<cfif isdefined('form.iSortCol_0')>
    ORDER BY
<cfloop from="0" to="#form.iSortingCols-1#" index="variables.i">
    #listGetAt(variables.fieldlist,form["iSortCol_#variables.i#"]+1)# #form["sSortDir_#variables.i#"]# <cfif variables.i is not form.iSortingCols-1>, </cfif>
</cfloop>

</cfif>
</cfquery>

<!--- strip off the table name from the values, otherwise it will break making the json --->
<cfset variables.fieldlist = ReplaceNoCase(variables.fieldlist,'#form.table#.','','all')>
```

It may be hard to tell, yet I am trying to figure out the best way to combine two table together to get my LOCATION_NAME which appears in a different table.

Thank you in advance to anyone that can help. This site shows the code I am trying to use. http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/4/29/JQuery-Datatables-plugin-example-using-a-server-side-data-request-coldfusion

Comment: Do you know how to write an sql query that selects fields from more than one table?  If not, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do a UNION an JOINS  and other methods, yet using the code from the datatable is appears as if you can only use one table. I was hoping someone knew a way around this?

Comment: Don't send table names as input parameters.  Just send search parameters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think you need to join on the UI? As an aside, you code is highly insecure and in vulnerable to all kinds of attacks.

Comment: I see that the table name is exposed. So should I just send the parameters and then on the CFM query the two tables? Does anyone know how to modify the JS to reflect this?

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start with the query, not using ColdFusion.  Then put it into a coldfusion page, .cfm or .cfc.  Then call it with ColdFusion code.  Then call it with jQuery.

Comment: Do you need your queries to be this dynamic, or do you have a fair idea of what they'll usually be? I think CF should completely disallow `FROM #form.x#` or any other `form` variable directly in a `cfquery` tag. The potential for accidentally allowed abuse is just too high. And as Dan said, work back to the query you want rather than the query Javascript tells it to send.

Comment: So I removed the table name and the select option. I wanted to ask. If I have the following below info shown that show the table column name, then is this non-secure? 


`code`
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#displayData').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "get_pending_applicants.cfm",
    "aoColumns": [ 
     {"sName": "EMPLOYEE_ID" , "sClass": "hidden"},
   ] 
`code`

Answer (score 0):

The issue had nothing to do with combinning my tables and more to do with the outdated ajax call. Using a left join for my query did the trick. My ajax call still needs some additional work. Thank you @Dan Bracuk 2 for your advice.